Amazon Neptune OpenCypher - What is the cause for "Operation terminated (internal error)" when using SET after MERGE?
I am running this simple query on an Amazon Neptune DB, using directly the Neptune API:
POST {{host}}/openCypher
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "query":"MERGE (t:Test {reference: $reference}) SET t.test=$test RETURN t",
    "parameters": {
        "reference": "test",
        "test": "100"
    }
}

But I get the following error as a response:
  "detailedMessage": "Operation terminated (internal error)",
  "code": "InternalFailureException",
  "message": "Operation terminated (internal error)"

What gives?
I have tried other examples setting test to different values. All of them worked, which makes the problem even stranger. See these below:
{     
"query":"MERGE (t:Test {reference: $reference}) SET t.test=$test RETURN t",     
"parameters": {         
   "reference": "test",         
   "test": "1"     
} 

{     
"query":"MERGE (t:Test {reference: $reference}) SET t.test=$test RETURN t",     
"parameters": {         
   "reference": "test",         
   "test": true     
} 

{     
"query":"MERGE (t:Test {reference: $reference}) SET t.test=$test RETURN t",     
"parameters": {         
   "reference": "test",         
   "test": false    
} 

{     
"query":"MERGE (t:Test {reference: $reference}) SET t.test=$test RETURN t",     
"parameters": {         
   "reference": "test",         
   "test": 1    
} 

{     
"query":"MERGE (t:Test {reference: $reference}) SET t.test=$test RETURN t",     
"parameters": {         
   "reference": "test",         
   "test": 100     
} 

{     
"query":"MERGE (t:Test {reference: $reference}) SET t.test=$test RETURN t",     
"parameters": {         
   "reference": "test",         
   "test": "test"    
} 


This bug has been fixed in version 1.3.2.1 of the Neptune Engine -https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/engine-releases-1.3.2.1.html

Fixed a bug where parameterized mutation queries throw an InternalFailureException when the parameter that was passed is not already present in the database.


That kind of query should work.  How are you sending the request to Neptune?
I just tested in a Neptune Notebook:
params = {
    'reference': 'test',
    'test': '100'
}

%%oc -qp params

MERGE (t:Test {reference: $reference}) 
SET t.test=$test 
RETURN t

{'~id': 'fbaa1199-9f2b-41ef-bdfe-27776e04a0d00', 
'~entityType': 'node', 
'~labels': ['Test'], 
'~properties': {'reference': 'test', 'test': '100'}}


I also tried the same via the AWS CLI:
!aws neptunedata execute-open-cypher-query \
   --open-cypher-query "MERGE (t:Test {reference: \$reference}) SET t.test=\$test RETURN t" \
   --parameters "{\"reference\": \"test\", \"test\": \"100\"}" \
   --endpoint-url "https://mycluster.cluster-abcdeolo6phb.us-west-2.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182"

{
    "results": [
        {
            "t": {
                "~id": "fbaa1199-9f2b-41ef-bdfe-27776e04a0d00",
                "~entityType": "node",
                "~labels": [
                    "Test"
                ],
                "~properties": {
                    "reference": "test",
                    "test": "100"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Or using the API directly:
awscurl -X POST https://mycluster.cluster-abcdeolo6phb.us-west-2.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/opencypher \
    --service neptune-db \
    --region us-west-2 \
    -d '{ \
        "query":"MERGE (t:Test {reference: $reference}) SET t.test=$test RETURN t", \
        "parameters": { \
            "reference": "test", \
            "test": "100" \
        } \
    }'

{
  "results": [{
      "t": {
        "~id": "fbaa1199-9f2b-41ef-bdfe-27776e04a0d00",
        "~entityType": "node",
        "~labels": ["Test"],
        "~properties": {
          "reference": "test",
          "test": "100"
        }
      }
    }]
}


Thanks for replying, Taylor. This is a direct call to the Neptune API, I have added more info to the post's description.

That works for me as well.  Which version of the Neptune engine are you using?  Are you able to open a support case?  This may require having one of the engineers look at your cluster directly to see what is causing the IFE.

Our instance is currently using version 1.3.2.0. Thanks for your testing Taylor, we have opened a support case to determine the issue, and will update the post with any findings.

Hi @Joats - you should be getting a response back from support soon.  But in the meantime, if you upgrade to 1.3.2.1, this issue should be fixed there.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/engine-releases-1.3.2.1.html

It was indeed fixed. Thanks once again for your help! :)
